# XPath string-join with apostrophs for dynamic value set

Tags: xml, xpath-2.0

i want to use XPATH to join a string. Actually i have a XML Structure like this:

```
<root>
 <employee>
  <employeePayrollID>1234567</employeePayrollID>
 </employee>
 <employee>
  <employeePayrollID>7654321</employeePayrollID>
 </employee>
 ...
</root>
```

I want to generate this **output**:
**'1234567','7654321'**

I'm using SAP CPI Content-Modifier to save this output as a Property.

propName: keys

sourceType: XPath

**sourceValue**: `string-join(//employeePayrollID,',')`

dataType: java.lang.String

**This leads to output: 1234567,7654321**

The challenge is to get this ' around the Id's, because i need it for further logic. I know this can be done with XSLT and so on. I really want to do it within this one liner XPath. Any chance?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the following two XPath-2.0 approaches:

1. The *inner-join*:

   ```
   concat("&apos;",string-join(//employeePayrollID,"&apos;,&apos;"),"&apos;")
   ```
2. The *outer-join*:

   ```
   string-join(for $emp in //employeePayrollID return concat("&apos;",$emp,"&apos;"),",")
   ```

Output should be as expected in both cases.
Switch the quotes if necessary.

Comment: I'm going with the inner join and it works :)